# output cvRect as an image

Tags: c, opencv

I just want to double check that the ROI that I've set is the correct ROI.
Hence, I want to be able to output the ROI as an image. The ROI uses cvRect as the 2nd argument and I don't really know how to convert that region into an image.
I want to be able to use the values in cvRect to determine the final image. Is this possible?

```
  cvSetImageROI(frame,cvRect((*pt[0]).x,(*pt[0]).y,abs(ROIwidth),abs(ROIheight)));
```

Comment: Note that you can write `pt[0]->x` instead of `(*pt[0]).x`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can copy the ROI into a temporary buffer, and save that buffer.

```
IplImage* roi = cvCreateImage(cvSize(abs(ROIwidth),abs(ROIheight)),frame->depth, frame->nChannels);

cvSetImageROI(frame,cvRect((*pt[0]).x,(*pt[0]).y,abs(ROIwidth),abs(ROIheight)));

cvCopy(frame,roi);

cvResetImageROI(frame);

cvSaveImage("roi.jpg",roi);

cvReleaseImage(&roi);
```

Answer (score 1):

With opencv c++ API which I recommand to use for beginner!

```
cv::Mat img; // my pre-loaded image
cv::Rect roi; // roi position (x,y,width,height)
cv::Mat img_roi(img, roi); // only create header = no copy!
cv::imwrite("my_roi.png",img_roi); // save
```

Note that conversion from `IplImage` to `cv::Mat` is direct using :

```
IplImage* img = cvLoadImage("my_img.jpg", 1);
cv::Mat new_img(img); // convert IplImage* -> Mat
```